# Using Template Blocks In go

Tags: go, go-templates, iris-go

I have multiple files inside `./views` folder, `_layout.html`, `view.html` and `search.html`
in `_layout.html` I have `{{template "PageCSS" .}}` and in `view.html` and `search.html` I customized it by `{{define "PageCSS"}}....{{end}}`
and my go code is

```
tmpl := iris.HTML("./views", ".html")
tmpl.Layout("\_layout.html")
rp.RegisterView(tmpl)


rp.Get("/search", func(ctx iris.Context) {
    ctx.View("search.html")
})
rp.Get("/view", func(ctx iris.Context) {
    ctx.View("view.html")
})`
```

but when I run it and go to search page I see view.html `{{define "PageCSS"}}....{{end}}` part
what should I do?
in fact it renders `{{define "PageCSS"}}....{{end}}` part of last `.html` file in `./views` folder for all other .html files

I tried this in Iris [doc](https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/main/_examples/view/template_html_5)